# How to replace MPI_Bcast with GPU-to-GPU broadcasting using NCCL

Tags: multiprocessing, mpi, nvidia

I would like to optimize MPI broadcast call for GPU-to-GPU communication. All I want to do is to replace the MPI_Bcast call with ncclBcast, but I need to create a NCCL communicator that uses MPI_COMM_WORLD, and that's where I fail. Once again, I try to replace the following one-liner

```
MPI_Bcast(buffer, length, MPI_Datatype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
```

with something like this

```
    int mpi_rank, mpi_size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_size);  // Obtain the total number of processes

    ncclUniqueId ncclId;
    ncclComm_t ncclComm;

    if (mpi_rank == 0) {
        ncclGetUniqueId(&ncclId);
    }
    
    MPI_Bcast(&ncclId, sizeof(ncclUniqueId), MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    ncclCommInitRank(&ncclComm, mpi_size, ncclId, mpi_rank);

    ncclBcast(buffer, length, ncclType, 0, ncclComm, cudaStreamDefault);

    ncclCommDestroy(ncclComm);
```

However, something is wrong, and I don't get what. In particular, ncclCommInitRank return value is not *ncclSuccess*. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix that? Any help is appreciated.